# What to do when I found a "theoretical" version of a practical question posted recently?

Tags: discussion

I recently found this question:

[Initializing structure as map value strange behavior (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921300/initializing-structure-as-map-value-strange-behavior-visual-studio)

While trying to answer it, I found strange behaviors in the various compiler, so digging a bit more I think I isolated the problem to a much smaller statement. Typically, I could write a question such as:

> Since c++11, narrowing conversion is not allowed in [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (including [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)). So basically:
>
> ```
> char c{1000}; // Does not compile with g++, clang, vc
> ```
>
> But:
>
> ```
> std::pair<char, double> p{1000, 1.0};
> ```
>
> Compiles with all compiler?
>   But:
>
> ```
> std::pair<char, double> p{1000, {1.0}};
> ```
>
> Does not compile with VC (error C2398), gives a warning with clang and compiles silently with g++...
>
> I would have expected VC behavior everywhere, i.e. a non-allowed narrowing conversion throwing an error. Which compiler is right?

This is not exactly the same questions, maybe it is a bit more theoretical than what the OP expect (I would be looking for some standard quotes, while he would be looking for a practical answer).

I am not an expert "language-lawyer", so I cannot answer this question by myself. Would it be ok to ask it on SO while linking to the original question? To me it may be seen as innapropriate since there is already a question with a similar content posted less than one hour ago...

Basically, if...

...someone posted a question, probably waiting for some practical answer, on *My compiler gives me this X error, what can I do to fix my code?*,

...would it be ok to ask a more theoretical question: *These compilers do not give the same result with this piece of code. Which one is right? What does the standard have to say about this?*.

Comment: That question is excessively sloppy, short from the many typos the snippet completely fails to demonstrate the problem.  Sounds to me you could ask this question in a much more constructive way.  Go for it.  Just VTC this one as a dup.

Comment: After you ask this question, could you post a link here, cannot find it.

Comment: @v010dya Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37928951/2666289

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ask your theoretical version. This has already happened numerous times and if the question is properly composed and meets site guidelines then they tend to go over rather well.

Asking a question about something counter-intuitive allows for more people in general to be aware of the issue, and also from a personal standpoint those tend to be the type of questions I enjoy answering.

I don't think it is a duplicate though, the question you link here shows a specific issue with their code, and an error which seems to not be reproducible given their example. Your question would be a narrow example of a simple snippet that for some reason has issues with the language interpretation based on compiler version. Those are two rather different problems.